# What is the difference between getPastEvents() vs events.MyEvent({ fromBlock: 0})?

Tags: ethereum, web3js, go-ethereum

What is the difference between using `myContract.getPastEvents()` to get past events and `using myContract.events.MyEvent({ fromBlock: 0, })` ?

Also, if I pass to `fromBlock` a block number that has not been mined yet, does it work as expected?

Comment: Maybe `MyEvent` does not handle old events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `MyEvent` lets you specify filters within a specific event type (you can filter by parameter values), whereas `getPastEvents` returns all events for an event type.

The syntax you posted is nearly identical. The main difference is `getPastEvents` will return all events that have occurred up until the block number the node you’re connected to is synced to. `MyEvent` will return those same events, plus will call the callback on any new events that occur as new blocks are added to the chain.